# jQuery ajax() Call Failing

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am writing a web-based application that makes a call to server to update a particular object in the server, from a REST-ful application.

This is the javascript code that I have written.

```
var sendUrl = url + "v1/items/" + itmId;
$.ajax({
    "type": "PUT",
    "url": sendUrl,
    //"data": {"name": nameVal, "description": descVal},
    "success": function() {
        alert('hai');  //refreshItems();
    },
    "complete": function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert (textStatus);
    }
});
```

When this code is executed, the server did not receive any request.  The browser did not show any update.

I am using Google Chrome as my browser.  So, I looked into Chrome's Javascript Console, the console showed this error:

[image: Error from Chrome's Console]

Are there any possible solutions to this problem?

---

Edit:

As suggested in one of the comments, I tried looking into Network Panel.  It seems it is not making a call to Server.

This is the screenshot of this particular request:
[image]

The image is very small.  The status is "(failed)" and Type is Pending

If Server does not have PUT configured, it would result in an Internal Server Error.  So, that is not happening here.

---

Edit

After trying the suggestion given in the answer,

This is the code:

```
var sendUrl = url + "v1/items/" + itmId;
$.ajax({
    "type": "PUT",
    "url": sendUrl,
    //"data": {"name": nameVal, "description": descVal},
    }).done(function ( ) {
        alert('OK');
    }).fail(function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

Here are the objects that has been logged:

[image]

Comment: Did you set up your server to handle `PUT` requests

Comment: Is that a typo error commenting out your `data`?

Comment: It's hard to guess from outside. First step would be investigating the particular call in Chrome Network Panel. You can filter for XHR Requests in the panel. Check if the Server sent any Response. Check if the Request contains typos or is missing mandatory fields. Also keep in mind that the Ports have to match when executing an AJAX call.

Comment: 1) Server is setup to handle PUT requests 2) commenting out data was intentional.  First time, I tried with data (no comments).  It was giving the same problem.

Comment: So, what is the response code from the server?!?!

Comment: Failed is not specific (it's not a HTTP response code). Like I suggested in my answer, check for the first parameter in the fail function `jqXHR` that should have a status property which should be a number. This number is the HTTP Response code. This should help you figure out what's wrong. Post this code **HERE** so we might help you

Comment: I have added this information as a new edit to the question.

Answer (score 7):

[Docs for jquery Ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[W3 specs regarding http/1.1 status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

---

First, as stated in the jQuery documentation

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Also, the fail function accepts the following parameters:

```
jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown
```

---

Since you're getting an error try the following code:

```
var sendUrl = url + "v1/items/" + itmId;
$.ajax({
    "type": "PUT",
    "url": sendUrl,
    //"data": {"name": nameVal, "description": descVal},

}).done(function ( ) {
    alert('OK');

}).fail(function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

This should output to the console usefull information about why the ajax call is not working.

If your webservice is working correctly, it should return a http status code. Here are some common response codes:

```
200 OK -> Everything is ok (it worked)
201 Created -> Ok too

400 Bad Request
401 Unauthorized
404 Not found
```

---

So, basically, the response you get should reflect why it's not working